# Take string as a parameter, return an object

Tags: java

I'm relatively new to Java, came across this method from an assignment and got hard stuck.
Also I didn't really know how to describe this situation as a question so bear with me with the tittle.

The requirement for the method is to "Construct and return a complete Person object from text",
given example was Person.createName("John")

```
public class Person {
    public static Person createName(String text) {
        //TO-DO
    }
}
```

Comment: This is called a [factory method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method). What you'll do in the method is to evaluate the input, and from there create an instance of the `Person` class, and then return it.

Comment: What does your "Person" object has for variables ? If we say it only has name then you could bring up the constructor which would set it's attribute name to the value passed to createName. And return the result of the constructor like this "return new Person(text)"

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out this is a factory method. You create and return an object in a `static method` of the same class. So something like this:

```
public class Person {
    public static Person createName(String text) {
        // Depending on your contructor.
        // You can further modify the person here if you need to.
        return Person(text):
    }
}
```

Also please have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp). w3schools is a excellent source to get started with `java`.